# Bind expressjs to a specific IP address

Tags: node.js, express

How can i bind a expressjs server to a specific IP

Something like

```
app.listen(8888, '192.168.0.101');
```

Equivalent to nodejs:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888,'192.168.0.101');
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

ExpressJS just [passes your parameters down](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/531f024e486c13eb6d7e2bc0966ea95b1567197a/lib/application.js#L595) to the `http` module when you call listen, so your example should work.

Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes sorry.. it was late :)
the error was a console.log message further down the code..

Comment: You've linked directly to master instead of a specific revision. The current link isn't helpful.

Comment: [http.listen doc page link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_handle_callback) for the lazy person like me who does not want to google for `http.listen` parameters :)

Answer (score 15):

```
var server = app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1',onServerListening);
```

In this case I want the server to respond only to connections using the 127.0.0.1 host name. Not 0.0.0.0, and not localhost. Only 127.0.0.1.