# How to bind http server with express object to a specific ip address?

Tags: node.js, express

How do i bind a specific address to a http object? Currently the default ip address for node.js is 127.0.0.1 and I want to change it to 0.0.0.0

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

http.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

How to achieve that?

edited: I added 0.0.0.0 but the default is still 127.0.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind expressjs to a specific IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986220/bind-expressjs-to-a-specific-ip-address)

Comment: @victorkohl I found that post but the link is not helping, I'm new to node.js

Comment: How are you doing it then? The code in your question isn't passing an IP to the `listen` function.

Comment: I tried passing "0.0.0.0" to http.listen() as the second argument , but it doesnt work, the ip address is still set 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`0.0.0.0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is not an actual IP that you can reach. Although it means bind to ***all*** IPs, or any IP. So no wonder it works for `127.0.0.1`. If you have set an IP address on one of your network devices (LAN, WiFi, virtual) it'll listen on those too.

---

> In python you can simply type `runserver 0.0.0.0` or something, so in Node.js is there an alternative?

[`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) gives you a list of arguments passed to node.

So if you run

```
node server.js 0.0.0.0
```

You'll get

```
process.argv[0] //=> "node" 
process.argv[1] //=> "server.js" 
process.argv[2] //=> "0.0.0.0"
```

Note that it's an array, so as long as you're sure you'll be running your file like that you can use `process.argv[2]` to specify that as the IP address you want to listen to.

```
http.listen(3000, process.argv[2]);
```

Generally though, you should set environment variable `IP`.

```
http.listen(3000, process.env[IP]);
```

Or all of them

```
http.listen(3000, process.argv[2] || process.env[IP] || "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: in python you can simply type 0.0.0.0 runserver or something, so in node.js there are no solution?

Comment: There's no built-in way to tell Node through a command line argument which IP to listen to, if that's what you mean, nope. You can program it with [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

Comment: So how do i put it in server.js? would you care demonstrate a little of code so that I could accept this answer

Comment: `http.listen(3000, process.argv[2])`