# Can I access a server hosted by a device on the same LAN as another one with no internet using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http, server, webserver, lan

Scenario: I want to provide an `http` response with a `.html` file when `192.186.xxx.xxx:PORT` is typed into Chrome search bar from a device which is connected to the same LAN (**with no internet access!!!**) as the device hosting the server.
I tried to do that, but Chrome is not loading anything as internet connection is not available.
So I'm wondering if this is possible and how to accomplish it. Any advice is really appreciated!

*EDIT*: I'm adding the code I'm using to be more clear:

```
const host = '192.168.4.2';
//const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile("./index.html", 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(contents);
        }
    });
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);

server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

*EDIT2*: I used `netstat -a` to look at active TCP connections on my laptop and it shows that my the IP address I'm using is actually bond to the laptop and it's listening. But still I cannot access it through chrome even though I use a internet connection with a new IP.

*EDIT3*: I'm not an expert in IT, could it be something related to firewall or proxy on the client side?

Comment: It is possible. How are you trying to start the server? You should make sure your server binds to the correct address, not just to loopback (e.g. 127.0.0.1)

Comment: I do it using nodejs http module to create a webserver. This indeed works when I use localhost as host ( I can access to the html page via Chrome). If this is changed to the device IP it doesn't work. Also I don't get any error from the JavaScript code with this setting, while if I use a wrong IP address a JavaScript error pops up as it cannot bind the server to a non-existing IP addres.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412303/how-to-bind-http-server-with-express-object-to-a-specific-ip-address

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm trying something different. I'll add the code to the question.

Comment: When you say "with no internet access" do you mean that you have a connection to the local LAN, but that LAN is not connected to the wider internet?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm using an Esp32 microcontroller board which generates a wireless LAN.